# Confusion about inner product between two functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, inner-products, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

In [this video](https://youtu.be/9-oxo_k69qs?t=4381), the professor defined a reproducing kernel function $K(x, \cdot)=\sum_{j=1}^{P}\phi_j(x)\phi_j$, and a function $f=\sum_{j=1}^Pw_j\phi_j$ and claim

$$
\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle= \sum_{j=1}^Pw_j\phi_j(x)=f(x) \tag 1
$$

He explained [here](https://youtu.be/9-oxo_k69qs?t=4470)

> if there is one-to-one correspondence between the functions and their coefficients, we can compute the inner product between these two functions by taking the inner product of the coefficients.

I don't understand why this is the case. More precisely, where is the $\phi_j$ in $K(x,\cdot)$ and $f$ gone? I've searched online, finding that the definition of the inner product between two functions $f$ and $g$ are

$$
\langle f,g\rangle=\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx \tag 2
$$

Based on the definition of Equation 2, shouldn't $\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle$ be computed as

$$
\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle= \sum_{j=1}^Pw_j\phi_j(x)\langle\phi_j,\phi_j\rangle
$$

Why would Equation 1 omit $\langle\phi_j,\phi_j\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is assumed that the $\phi_j$'s form an orthonormal basis. Therefore $\langle \phi_j,\phi_k \rangle=0$ if $j\neq k$ and $\langle \phi_j,\phi_j \rangle=1$.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. Why is an orthonormal basis assumed here? Does it mean that any reproducing kernel can be regarded as the inner product of two orthonormal bases?

Comment: It's because the discussion is centered around reproducing kernels with respect to a Hilbert space. Hence, you know there exists an orthonormal basis for your underlying function space.

Comment: If this fact about Hilbert spaces is unfamiliar to you, you can read about orthonormal bases in Hilbert spaces here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthonormal_bases

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew. I see your point. So any reproducing kernel takes the form of $K(x_1, x_2)=\sum_{j=1}^{P}\phi_j(x_1)\phi_j(x_2)$, where $\phi_j$'s form an orthonormal basis. Am I right?

Comment: Hi @Andrew. One more question. $K(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Pc_ic_j\phi_i(x_1)\phi_j(x_2)$. this does not seem to follow the property $\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle=f(x)\quad\forall f\in\mathcal H$

Comment: To be a bit more general, I think you want $K(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Pc_ic_j\phi_i(x_1)\phi_j(x_2)$, but your expression is essentially correct. And yes it does! What I wrote is the most general possible form. In my example, just take $c_ic_j=w_j$. Then by orthogonality, every term such that $i\neq j$ is zero in the inner product, and you end up write at the desired expression.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. I'm still confused. If $K(x_1,x_2)=\sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Pc_ic_j\phi_i(x_1)\phi_j(x_2)$, then $K(x,\cdot)=\sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Pc_ic_j\phi_i(x)\phi_j$. From it, I can only derive $\langle f,K(x,\cdot)\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^Pw_j\phi_j(x)c_jc_j\ne \sum_{j=1}^Pw_j\phi_j(x)$, where $f$ is defined in the question.

Comment: Take $c_ic_j=1$. Those were just general coefficients. There is nothing deep behind them.

Comment: Hi @Andrew. If we take $c_ic_j=1$, then why should we add them in the first place?

Comment: Ok, nevermind. Forget anything about $c_i$ or $c_j$.